# CDI dependency injection fails on classes implementing interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, code-injection

Let's have this example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void foo();
}
```

and implementing class:

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void foo() {...}
}
```

When I try to inject dependent class MyResource into MyInterfaceImpl nothing happens without any error or warning however the MyResource is not injected so the code fails with NullPointerException:

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
    @Inject
    private MyResource resource;

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        resource.doAnything() <-- will throw NullPointerException
    }
}
```

I packaged this in .war archive and deployed on Glassfish v4 with a simple Jersey application. I also tried to put beans.xml to WEB-INF and META-INF.

After removing the "implements MyInterface" from MyInterfaceImpl class the injection works. Why is the dependency injection not working on classes implementing an interface?

Comment: Please show how you get your `MyInterfaceImpl` objects.

Comment: Could you provide a small project which reproduces your issue, because there's probably something more you missed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: your comment helped me to think again and read more about the CDI. I created the object with the 'new' operator. After I changed it to be created by container by injecting it everything worked.